# android app project over RSE

Tags: android, eclipse

I wonder if anyone can tell me if it is possible to save an android app on a server and use the RSE Eclipse plugin to edit it ?

This has become necessary for me so I don't have to physically be at work to continue work on a project.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this seems obvious...but is there no way you can work on the app locally and save your changes to the server using RSE...or even better, commit the changes using some version control system?

Comment: Obvious or not - thanks for the input. I am not familiar with version control systems yet. My objective presently is to be able to access my ongoing Android app project from work and from home. So I guess uploading via RSE is ideal for me. Only I have spent the last couple of minutes trying to setup a Remote Connection with no joy. It asks me for a System Type, I type in Linux but the next button remains inactive.